# Как из cs файла вычленить классы, методы и др. и сделать подсветку кода?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, редактор

Хочу написать новый интерфейс для просмотра кода C#, используя wpf или winForms. 
    Для этого нужно из sc файлов вычленять классы, методы и др. и подсвечивать код, как в visual studio (или других средах).
    Подскажите, есть ли готовые решения такой проблемы. Может, api студии, через который можно получить текст методов и классов. 
Возможно ли сделать расширение visual studio, которое позволит по-другому просматривать код? Как-то интегрировать в студию wpf-приложение

Comment: готовое решение - это visual studio. заходите в настройки и делайте как вам нужно ) Ну а вообще - если это нужно в целях обучения, то какие готовые решения вы ожидаете ? либу которая за вас сделает? если есть идея - думайте как решить.

Comment: Я хочу сделать интерфейс для просмотра кода. Было бы намного проще, если бы не надо было возиться подсветкой кода и вычленениями сущностей. На самом деле без такого готового решения моя задача не реализуема

Comment: думаю в `vs code` и в `notepad++` есть плагины для подсветки...но как они работают и можно ли юзать - осталось проверить Вам